# firebase ui phone authentication not working properly

Tags: android

I'm trying to add phone authentication with the firebase-ui-auth library. First in the (onActivityResult) method when the user successfully signed in, I added an Intent to take the user to MainActivity. But then I wanted to change the MainActivity to another Activity it doesn't work and still takes the user to the MainActivity! Even I passed another activity to the Intent rather than MainActivity!

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // RC_SIGN_IN is the request code you passed into startActivityForResult(...) when starting the sign in flow.
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);

        // Successfully signed in
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();



        } else {// show a massage
            }

}}
```

Comment: You are taking user to main activity on your code. And if this is your problem it's not about firebase phone auth. Could you elaborate your question and situation ?

Comment: FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();   the problem is when I want to change the MainActivity to UserInfoActivity for instance it still goes to the MainActivity. I dont know the reson!   -Mustafa

Comment: @MedinaAbdulghaffar Your problem seems like it needs to be under another topic. Please first search for usage of intent and if still problem continues create another question with more information and right context.